# Javascript: How do I "kill" the loading of an object?

Tags: javascript, html

I reference objects (images, scripts, iframes, etc) from other websites. Sometimes, the other site is down, and I have to wait about 30 seconds for my browser to "skip" the object. How can I "skip" the object after, for example, 5 seconds?

Here's some sample code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/). Here's a snippet straight from its home page:

> yepnope.js has the capability to do resource fallbacks and still download
>   dependent scripts in parallel with the first. More clearly:
>
> ```
> yepnope([{
>   load: 'http:/­/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js',
>   complete: function () {
>     if (!window.jQuery) {
>       yepnope('local/jquery.min.js');
>     }
>   }
> }, {
>   load: 'jquery.plugin.js',
>   complete: function () {
>     jQuery(function () {
>       jQuery('div').plugin();
>     });
>   }
> }]);
> ```

I suggest investigating yepnope and other existing script loaders before deciding whether to roll your own. These loaders are quite small (yepnope claims to be 1.6 kB), so there's not much to gain by writing your own solution.

Comment: Great point. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) comes with yepnope iirc, and there's also [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has the `async` attribute for `script` elements that offsets this difficulty by allowing scripts to load asynchronously. Some browsers additionally implement a non-standard `defer` attribute that is similar, [but not exactly the same](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async). As for resources besides `scripts`, such as images, you can actually use JavaScript to cause them to load asynchronously (for example, by creating the image element on the fly). The downside to this approach is that if your asynchronous JavaScript subsequently causes asynchronous images to load, you run a very high risk of a [FOUC](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/).